# React query prefetch dynamic queries

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I would like to prefetch dynamic number of queries with reach query, but I haven't seen anywhere in the docs that you can do that.

Is there a way of prefetching this kind of queries?

```
export const useGetIncome = (
    persons: { id: string; incomeData: TransformerIncomeRequestDto }[]
) =>
    useQueries({
        queries: persons.map((person) => {
            return {
                queryKey: ["income", person.ident],
                queryFn: async (): Promise<TransformerIncomeRequestDto> => {
                    const { data } = await INCOME_API.transformer.transformerIncome(
                        person.incomeData
                    );
                    return data;
                },
                staleTime: Infinity,
                suspense: true,
            };
        }),
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call `queryClient.prefetchQuery` in a loop if you know the personIds:

```
personIds.map(ident => {
  queryClient.prefetchQuery({
    queryKey: ["income", ident],
    queryFn: async (): Promise<TransformerIncomeRequestDto> => ...
  })
})
```